# Enviar múltiples valores con checkbox utilizando ajax y php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Excelente día amigos, estoy realizando un sitio en el cual debo enviar distintas opciones utilizando los checkboxes, sin embargo, al querer procesarlo en PHP me arroja el siguiente mensaje

> "
> **Warning**:  Undefined array key "materias" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moca\administrador\config\materias_vacantes.php** on line **22**
>
> **Warning**:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moca\administrador\config\materias_vacantes.php** on line **22**
> {"success":1}"

por lo que me ha resultado imposible continuar desde ahí, lo tengo distribuido de la siguiente materia:

```
    <ul>
        <li><input name="materias[]" type="checkbox" value="0" /></li>
        <li><input name="materias[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></li>
        <li><input name="materias[]" type="checkbox" value="3" /></li>
        <li><input name="materias[]" type="checkbox" value="4" /></li>
        <li><input name="materias[]" type="checkbox" value="5" /></li>
    </ul>
   <button type="button" onclick="mover();" class="btn btn-warning btn-md btn-block">Mover</button>
```

mis checkbox de prueba, a continuación, JavaScript:

```
function mover() {

    //obtenemos datos.
    var mate =JSON.stringify({materias: $('[name="materias[]"]').serializeArray()});
    
    

    console.log(mate);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../administrador/config/materias_vacantes.php' + '?cambio=1',
        data: mate,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
```

y por ultimo el php donde recepciono los datos:

```
if(isset($_GET['cambio'])){
foreach($_GET['materias'] as $materia){
    echo $materia;
}
echo json_encode(["success"=>1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores

1. La función que debes ocupar es serialize() y está ya hace todo el trabajo, no tienes necesidad de convertir a JSON. (A menos que quieras enviar un json)
2. Si envías por POST, en php recibes por post
3. Tienes un `echo $materia;` que está mal. Pero supongo que era con fines de testeo. El retorno debe ser en JSON, pues eso le indicaste en dataType:'json'

```
function mover() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Otrot.php?cambio=1',
        data: $('[name="materias[]"]').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log("Bien");
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data, status) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
}
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['cambio'])){
    foreach($_POST['materias'] as $materia){
      
    }
    echo json_encode($_POST['materias']);
}
?>
```

Esto me muestra el depurador cuando hago check en los inputs cuyos valor son 3 y 4
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]